# Easy Directional Derivative problem I can't get right

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have an exam tomorrow and can't seem to get this problem right:

Find the directional derivative of $f(x,y) = ye^{-x}$ at $a=(0,1)$ in the direction of $v=\frac15(3,4)$.

I tried solving it with gradient $\cdot$ $v$ as well as using the regular definition of directional derivative.

Thanks

Comment: Actually I just got it using the dot product way. Could someone explain using lim [f(a+vt)-f(a)]/t  ?

Comment: So show us your work. $\nabla f(0,1) = (-1,1)$, and $\nabla f(0,1)\cdot \frac15(3,4) = \frac 15$.

Comment: Hey you're the author! I just got it that way, I'm now trying to understand using the other definition.      I reached lim [(1+4/5t)e^(-3/5t)-1]/t but don't know past that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the limit definition amounts to using the definition of the derivative of a function of a single variable. We want
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac {f(0+\frac35t, 1+\frac45t) - f(0,1)}t = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{(1+\frac45 t)e^{-\frac35t} - 1}t = \left.\frac d{dt}\right|_{t=0} \left[(1+\frac45t)e^{-\frac35t}\right]= \frac45 - \frac35 = \frac15\,.$$

Comment: @MathNoob: If this doesn't answer your question, let me know. If it does, please accept the answer so we know we're done with this question :)